# How to start Apache Drill in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-drill

[This link](https://drill.apache.org/docs/running-drill-on-docker/) explains how to run Apache Drill on Docker.

```
docker run -i --name drill-1.18.0 -p 8047:8047 -t apache/drill:1.18.0 /bin/bash
```

I need to run it on Docker Compose, so I set it up:

```
   version: "3.0"
   services:
      drill:
        image: apache/drill:latest
        ports:
          - "8047:8047"
        volumes:
          - vol_dask_data:/data
        entrypoint:
          - /bin/bash
```

And start it like so:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

But the container ends without doing anything, even though I start docker compose with `-d`.

How to start Drill in Docker Compose?

Comment: The `entrypoint:` replaces the command the container would normally run; you shouldn't usually need to include that line in a `docker-compose.yml` file.  Similarly in your `docker run` command you shouldn't normally need to put an explicit `/bin/bash` command at the end; leave off the command and let the container run the program built into the Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks, the `docker run` is the example given by Apache. I removed the `entrypoint:` and still the container ends without doing anything. The container should be a server waiting for requests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Drill Dockerfile](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/distribution/Dockerfile) ends with:

```
ENTRYPOINT /opt/drill/bin/drill-embedded
```

In the `docker run` command, this particular construction completely ignores the command given after the image name.  In your Compose setup, you replace this (with an `entrypoint:` line) with a Bash shell, but this shell will immediately exit.

The other important difference between the `docker run` command and the Compose setup is the `-it` options.  If you try that `docker run` command without either `-i` or `-t` you will see the Drill prompt, and then the container will immediately exit.  If you add back `-i` then it will wait for a command, and while it's doing that it will accept network connections.  The Compose equivalent to this is the `stdin_open: true` command.

With this `docker-compose.yml` I can see the Drill UI on `http://localhost:8047`:

```yaml
version: "3.8"        # a more current version
services:
  drill:
    image: apache/drill:latest
    ports:
      - "8047:8047"
    stdin_open: true  # add this line
                      # do not override entrypoint: or command:
                      # include volumes: if required
```